# Is it possible to nest if/else statements in handlebars templates?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, handlebars.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to nest multiple if/else statements using handlebars? All my attempts so far have resulted in compile errors, what I'd like to do is as follows:

```
{{if address}}
    <ul>
    <li>address.line1</li>
    <li>address.line2</li>
    {{if address.line3}}<li>address.line3</li>{{/if}}
    {{if address.line4}}<li>address.line4</li>{{/if}}
{{else}}
   No address given
{{/if}}
```

Is what I'm attempting here achievable? It always results in parser errors, thusfar I've got around it by writing a helper to deal with spitting out the address (which deals with conditionality of line3/line4 in javascript):

```
{{if address}}
    {{formatAddress address}}
{{else}}
   No address given
{{/if}}
```

While this works, it would be nice not to have to write a helper function for every instance of this sort of simple conditionality.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I believe ifs need a preceding #

Try this.

```
{{#if address}}
    <ul>
        <li>address.line1</li>
        <li>address.line2</li>
        {{#if address.line3}}<li>address.line3</li>{{/if}}
        {{#if address.line4}}<li>address.line4</li>{{/if}}
    </ul>
{{else}}
   No address given
{{/if}}
```